# Is there an equivalent of Java's this in Scala constructors?

Tags: scala

I have a Scala 2.11 constructor where I want one of the class' attributes to have the same name as one of the parameters in the constructor.

```
class Transition( next: Int ) {
    this.next = next // works in Java
}
```

This doesn't compile. I'm wondering what the equivalent of the assignment statement is in Scala.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scala makes your life easy:

```
class Transition(val next: Int)
```

The `val` will make the constructor parameter into a field.

Comment: Well, that's relatively painless.